# 413 Request Entity Too Large Nginx client_max_body_size configurado

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-server

Tengo una aplicación corriendo en Nginx, la cual fue migrada desde Apache, donde funcionaba sin problemas. La carga de archivos al servidor funciona, menos para archivos que pesen más de 2 megas en total, ya que recibo este error cuando las intento cargar:

[image: Mensaje de error]

Actualmente tengo configurados los parámetros client_max_body_size en 25M y el client_body_buffer_size en 16k en el **nginx.conf** (tanto en el bloque server como en el local y en el http), así como el upload_max_filesize en 25M, el max_file_uploads en 200 y el post_max_size en 25M en el **php.ini**.

He intentado modificar la configuración en el location / del archivo de configuración del sites-enabled para ver si Nginx me está tomando esa configuración y no la configuración general, pero la respuesta sigue siendo la misma, después de reiniciar los servicios del php7.4-fpm y del nginx. Incluso he configurado el client_max_body_size en 0, para evitar el chequeo de esa directiva, pero todo sigue igual.

No sé si es que requiero cambiar alguna configuración, moverla de lugar o qué, por lo que les adjunto el nginx.conf, el php.ini y el archivo de configuración del sitio, para ver si me pueden ayudar con esto.

nginx.conf:

```
include /etc/Nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {

    map $remote_addr $ip_anonym1 {
    default 0.0.0;
    "~(?P<ip>(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+))\.\d+" $ip;
    "~(?P<ip>[^:]+:[^:]+):" $ip;
}

map $remote_addr $ip_anonym2 {
    default .0;
    "~(?P<ip>(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+))\.\d+" .0;
    "~(?P<ip>[^:]+:[^:]+):" ::;
}

map $ip_anonym1$ip_anonym2 $ip_anonymized {
    default 0.0.0.0;
    "~(?P<ip>.*)" $ip;
}

log_format anonymized '$ip_anonymized - $remote_user [$time_local] '
'"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
'"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';


    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 0;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


server {
    #Configuración de puerto
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 444;

        client_max_body_size 0;
        client_body_buffer_size 16k;

        root /local;

    #Ubicación por defecto de los logs
        access_log /var/www/log/access.log;
        error_log /var/www/log/error.log;

    #Configuración para archivos robots.txt
        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

    #Denegar acceso a archivos txt o de logs
        location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
                deny all;
        }

    #Denegar acceso a cuaqluier script php dentro de rutas aparte a index.php
        location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
                return 403;
        }

    #Denegar acceso a directorios privados
        location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
                return 403;
        }

    #Responder la aplicación unicamente por el archivo index.php interpretando parametros querystring
        location / {
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 300000;
                location ~* ^(?:.+\.(?:htaccess|make|txt|engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(?:\.php)?|xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|/Entries.*|/Repository|/Root|/Tag|/Template)$ {
                        return 404;
                }
                try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
        }

    #Condigo para interpretación de lenguaje PHP.
        location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
                client_max_body_size 0;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
                fastcgi_param BASE_PATH $document_root;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
                fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME $server_name;
                keepalive_timeout 0;
                fastcgi_buffers 32 32k;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        }

}
```

- Archivo de configuración del sitio:

  ```
  server {
   ## Configura el puerto 80 como puerto de acceso ##
   listen 80;

   ## Asigna un nombre al servidor ##
   server_name [oculto_nombre_por_precaución];

   ## Configura ubicación de los archivos de log ##
   error_log  [oculto_nombre_por_precaución];

   ## Define una ruta raíz para el aplicativo ##
   root  [oculto_nombre_por_precaución];

   ## Define los tipos de archivo index ##
   index index.html index.php;

   ## Bloque de personalización de mensajes de error ##
   error_page 400 /error/400.html;
   error_page 401 /error/401.html;
   error_page 403 /error/403.html;
   error_page 404 /error/404.html;
   error_page 405 /error/405.html;
   error_page 500 /error/500.html;
   error_page 502 /error/502.html;
   error_page 503 /error/503.html;

   location  /error/ {
       internal;
   }
   ## Fin del bloque de personalización de mensajes de error ##

   ## Bloque de redirección de las rutas de archivos ##
   ## Si el archivo existe, lo usa ##
   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri @mainRules;
   }

   ## Si no existe, redirige al index, agregando la URL como parámetro para el    ruteo del aplicativo ##
   location @mainRules {
       rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1;
   }

   location /[oculto_nombre_por_precaución]/ {
       try_files $uri $uri/ @secondaryRules;
   }

   location @secondaryRules {
       rewrite ^(.+)$ /[oculto_nombre_por_precaución]/index.php?url=$1;
   }
   ## Fin del bloque de redirección de las rutas de archivos ##

   ## Bloque de redirección de las rutas de Ajax ##
   location /ajax/ {
       try_files $uri $uri/ @ajaxRules;
   }

   location @ajaxRules {
       rewrite ^(.+)$ /ajax/index.php?url=$1;
   }

   location /[oculto_nombre_por_precaución]/ajax/ {
       try_files $uri $uri/ @secondAjaxRules;
   }

   location @secondAjaxRules {
       rewrite ^(.+)$ /[oculto_nombre_por_precaución]/ajax/index.php?url=$1;
   }
   ## Fin del bloque de redirección de las rutas de Ajax ##

   location ~ ^/[oculto_nombre_por_precaución]/_app/ {
       deny all;
       return 401;
   }

   location = /favicon.ico {
       log_not_found off;
       access_log off;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
       fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
       send_timeout 1200;
       proxy_read_timeout 1200;
       proxy_connect_timeout 120;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }
  ```

  server{
          listen 443 ssl;
          server_name [oculto_nombre_por_precaución];
          return 301 [oculto_nombre_por_precaución];
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La directiva **client_max_body_size** la debes establecer en la seccion **http**, **server** o **location** - no en todas - del archivo **nginx.conf**. En el contexto **http** se aplica a todas las aplicacion del servidor nginx, por ejemplo:

```
http {
...
client_max_body_size 50M;
}
```

en el contexto server se aplica a un sitio en concreto

```
server {
...
client_max_body_size 50M;
}
```

para aplicarlo a una sola ruta en especifico se haria

```
location /upload {
...
client_max_body_size 50M;
}
```

Ahora bien, revisando tu archivo veo que tienes la directiva regada por todas las secciones, solo bastaria con colocarla en la seccion http para cubrir todos los servers y las rutas. Aca te dejo tu archivo modificado

```
 include /etc/Nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    user www-data;
    worker_processes auto;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
            worker_connections 768;
            multi_accept on;
    }

    http {
        map $remote_addr $ip_anonym1 {
        default 0.0.0;
        "~(?P<ip>(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+))\.\d+" $ip;
        "~(?P<ip>[^:]+:[^:]+):" $ip;
    }

    map $remote_addr $ip_anonym2 {
        default .0;
        "~(?P<ip>(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+))\.\d+" .0;
        "~(?P<ip>[^:]+:[^:]+):" ::;
    }

    map $ip_anonym1$ip_anonym2 $ip_anonymized {
        default 0.0.0.0;
        "~(?P<ip>.*)" $ip;
    }

    log_format anonymized '$ip_anonymized - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';


        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 15;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


    server {
        #Configuración de puerto
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
            server_name _;
            return 444;

            client_body_buffer_size 16k;

            root /local;

        #Ubicación por defecto de los logs
            access_log /var/www/log/access.log;
            error_log /var/www/log/error.log;

        #Configuración para archivos robots.txt
            location = /robots.txt {
                    allow all;
                    log_not_found off;
                    access_log off;
            }

        #Denegar acceso a archivos txt o de logs
            location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
                    deny all;
            }

        #Denegar acceso a cuaqluier script php dentro de rutas aparte a index.php
            location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
                    return 403;
            }

        #Denegar acceso a directorios privados
            location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
                    return 403;
            }

        #Responder la aplicación unicamente por el archivo index.php interpretando parametros querystring
            location / {
                    proxy_read_timeout 300000;
                    location ~* ^(?:.+\.(?:htaccess|make|txt|engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(?:\.php)?|xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|/Entries.*|/Repository|/Root|/Tag|/Template)$ {
                            return 404;
                    }
                    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
            }

        #Condigo para interpretación de lenguaje PHP.
            location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
                    fastcgi_param BASE_PATH $document_root;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
                    fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME $server_name;
                    keepalive_timeout 0;
                    fastcgi_buffers 32 32k;
                    fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            }

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    }
```

Comment: Sí, está en varios lados porque lo había intentado poner en varios lugares y no lograba que funcionara. Reemplacé mi archivo con el que me dejaste y el error persiste. Incluso intenté poniendo el 50M o el 0, con el mismo archivo que me enviaste, y sigo teniendo el mismo error.

Comment: ejecuta el comando nginx -T y nos compartes la salida

Comment: Claro, mira, la respuesta es esta: 
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
El archivo de esa ruta es el que estoy modificando.

Comment: ejecuta nginx -T | grep client_max_body_size

Comment: Lo corrí y salió esto:
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
    client_max_body_size 50m;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
                # client_max_body_size 0;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
Volví a abrir el archivo de configuración (tanto el nginx.conf como el del sitio, en sites-enabled) y no encuentro esa instrucción en más lugares. ¿Dónde pueden estar las repetidas?

Comment: situate en la ruta /etc/nginx y ejecuta grep -R 'client_max_body_size' para que puedas ver todos los archivos donde tienes la directiva configurada, si te da error de acceso en algunas rutas ejecutalo como root

Comment: Encontró varios, pero el límite de respuestas de este comentario no me deja ponerlos todos, por lo que te los pongo en esta imagen: https://i.ibb.co/X2gwqgY/Captura.png. ¿Los modifico todos?